# emailVerificationSSPRControl isn't rendering intro_msg

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

For some reason Azure B2C `emailVerificationSSPRControl` isn't rendering the `intro_message` text, but only shows empty green box. Additional UI texts after submitting email display correctly. In fact, even if I don't define any LocalizedString values, it is also empty as if the control would be missing that definition. Is there something that could be done to the issue?

*intro_message in first line is not shown, but the success_send_code_msg works:*
[image: intro_message not shown, but the success_send_code_msg works]

*intro_message empty:*

[image: intro_message empty]

*success_send_code_msg shows correctly:*

[image: success_send_code_msg shows correctly]

**UPDATE**:

For `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.0.0` it shows it CORRECTLY:

[image]

For `2.1.0` and `2.1.2` it shows the empty green bar, so the problem is in `2.1.X`.

Comment: have you tried ver_intro_msg instead?

Comment: what happens if you remove the localised line entirely?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT If I remove the localized line entirely, I get empty green box without any text, as in second picture.

Comment: Ok so its not the fault of the localisation entry. Can you try an older page layout version?

Comment: Updated description, issue would seem to occur on 2.1.X versions. @JasSuri-MSFT

Answer (score 1):

While not really fixing the issue, Microsoft has updated [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#verification-display-control-user-interface-elements) saying you need to manually show the `intro_msg` element using custom CSS.

From the article: "*The intro_msg element is hidden, and not shown on the self-asserted page. To make it visible, use the HTML customiztion with Cascading Style Sheets. For example:*

`.verificationInfoText div{display: block!important}`"

For the record, the green box isn't related to `intro_msg`, but to `success_send_code_msg` that is displayed after requesting the verification code. Why it is incorrectly displayed on screen is a different bug.

Comment: While this solution does solve the problem temporarily it can cause issues when this is info_message supposed to be display: none, such as when the success_message is displayed. Will cause two messages to be shown. I was forced to use a mutation observer and use javascript to get the message to be displayed at the correct time.

Comment: @code_disciple it's really annoying... I solve it with this css code: `#emailVerificationSSPRControl:has(#emailVerificationSSPRControl_success_message[aria-hidden="true"]) #emailVerificationSSPRControl_info_message {
 display: block !important;
}`